# source code for lccs_10_3Beta.swc

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I am developing a LCCS application with SDK 4.5 and lccs_10_3Beta.swc. it shares audio, video and screen. Where can i get the Code for the particular SWC.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe LCCS is packed with all the below things
SDK Navigator,Compiled libraries,Source code,Server scripts,Local Connection Server.
by downloading you also get the source. for more information please 
refer [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/services/collaboration.html)